# Safety of Self-signed certificate in a point-to-point socket with SSL

Tags: sockets, security, ssl

I would like to confirm what I understood about using self-signed certificates if used for a point-to-point socket with SSL.

Suppose I only have 1 client and 1 server. I generate a self-signed certificate and install the certificate on both the server and the client. The machines otherwise accept no other certificates.

Does this mean that in order for any MITM attacks, the attacker must physically hack into one of the machines to obtain the certificate?

What other vulnerabilities does this setup present if these are the only two machines that will be using the certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: Certificates alone don't prevent MITM attacks if the client and server do not actually validate the certificates they receive during handshaking.  For instance, OpenSSL has options to enable/disable peer validations, and a callback for providing certificates to app code so it can do its own validations on top of any default validations OpenSSL may perform.

Comment: This question really belongs in https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. In the scenario you describe, the certificate is only used as a convenient way to move the public key to another machine.

If you configure the client and server to only trust this certificate, your communication is secure as long as you can keep your private key safe.

Other attack vectors are exploiting other vulnerabilities in your application or the operating system it runs in.